# How can I insert circled numbers with text in button label/text, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to insert circled numbers with (a-z) text on button labels/text in a desktop vb.net application.  Wingdings 2 font has what I need for the circled numbers but has no regular (a-z) text and the button font property does not allow two different fonts in the same button label/text.

In scouring the internet, I can find nothing, but I am sure I am not the first to need this feature.

The goal is to have a circled number at the beginning of each button label/text, so that the user can  click the buttons in the right sequence.

Comment: A RichTextBox can do multiple fonts.  See [SelectionFont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont?view=net-5.0)

Comment: If there is a requirement to click the buttons in a particular order, perhaps you could have just one button, maybe labelled "Next", that does the actions in the correct sequence.

Comment: You can always use an Image or paint the Text yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be be to paste them in as Unicode in most fonts.  Here are some Sans Serif ones, just try to copy and paste them with the rest of your button text:

➀ ➁ ➂ ➃ ➄ ➅ ➆ ➇ ➈ ➉

If this does not work for you, You may want to try a button image instead.  Maybe use something like Paint.Net to make the text you want into an image, and then set that as the button image.  I'm not sure if you can do that in a sizable way with SVG or PNG or if you would have to make several images for different sizes and use code to switch them.

FYI, I got these characters from this site, if you want more options: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_circled_numbers.html

Comment: FWIW - the circle 0 came out as a 'pause' looking character.  The others looked great.

Comment: I was able to use form load to enter the unicode numbers with the text:  Example...BtnLoad.Text = Chrw(9312) & "  Load"   However the character (one in a circle) Is very small and increasing the font size of the text didn't change the size.of the character. I have seen no discussion of the unicode sizing.

Comment: @EdJenkins Unicode characters should size with size with the other characters (technically, they're all Unicode).  Maybe try a different base font and see if they size better.  If that doesn't work, you may need to use an image for your button instead. (I have updated my answer with that).  If one of these works, please let me know so that I cna update my answer appropiately.